(The) English taught in Japan is American English

It is often said that (the) English taught in Japan is American
English, but that is misleading. In fact, almost all English grammar
books for Japanese high school students cover both American English
grammar and British English grammar.

Is the mandatory or optional?
If it is optional, is there any difference in connotation between "English taught in Japan" and "the English taught in Japan"?

Yes, "the" is needed there.  It is distinguishing between various Englishes.  But you could say "It is often said that English as taught in Japan is American English."

Thank you, TimR. Perhaps, "English as taught in Japan" = "English as it is taught in Japan".

Yes, "English" is understood to be the subject of the passive construction in the defining relative clause.   The pronoun is not necessary but is permissible, in which case one needs "is" as well.

Sometimes, even with words that are usually non-count and general, we need to talk about specific "instances" of them.
For instance, "chocolate pudding" is usually just a general type of thing; we have "some" chocolate pudding, and don't use articles.* But a restaurant might say "Our chocolate pudding is made with Belgian chocolate," and mean by that "Our specific instance of the general thing." Similarly, you might say about that restaurant, "The chocolate pudding served there is made with Belgian chocolate."
Or, for an even more abstract example, a poet might write something about "the love I feel for you." Of course "love" isn't usually a "the," but they mean "the singular instance that I feel, out of the general experience of love."

* This is kind of a bad example, since we might say "I'll have a chocolate pudding" to mean "a serving of it," or "I'll have the chocolate pudding" to mean "the menu item that is chocolate pudding." Never mind these for now.
